# Is GRACE satellite data freely available?

Tags: data, satellite

Is GRACE (Gravity Recovery And Climate Experiment) satellite data freely downloadable/available to users?

Comment: What research have you done on this topic so far?

Comment: So far nothing has been done related to this topic. We are working for different applications of satellite data on natural rubber. in this line i wlould like to know whether the GRACE satellite data is freely available to public or only through cost?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would better suited to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, ALL of NASA's scientific data is freely available. You can find the datasets you need by either searching NASA's [data portal](https://data.nasa.gov/data?search=grace&category=), or in mission-specific [sites](http://www.csr.utexas.edu/grace/science_links.html) and hubs.